# Ruby on Rails command won't execute (even running directly from installation directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, batch-file, command-line

I have just installed `Ruby on Rails` on `Windows 10` using the `Rails Installer`, and am attempting to create a new project. However, even when I am actually in the `\bin` directory and am looking straight at `rails.bat`, the system refuses to respond to the `rails` command. Any ideas? I am using `RailsInstaller3.2.0`

[image]

Contents of the rails.bat file as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe"     "C:/Users/emachnic/GitRepos/railsinstaller-windows/stage/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails" %1     %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Note: `Ruby.exe` does execute, and the `ruby` command can be run from any directory within the `Windows` Command Line shell (`\bin` is a recognised global file path within the shell).

Comment: There's either something being called in rails.bat that isn't where the script expects it to be, or C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin is not located in the `%PATH%` system variable.

Comment: If it was to do with the ```\bin``` directory not being present in the ```%PATH%``` system variable then there would be no problem running directly from the directory itself. ```%PATH%``` just maps a particular directory globally. Not having something in ```%PATH``` won't stop it executing when called directly from the file's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in the `rails.bat` file appeared to have been set wrongly by the `RailsInstaller`. `C:\Users\emachnic\` does not appear to exist on my machine through the default Windows command line shell as experienced at the time of posting (though I suspect it may be a remnant of the initial setup process run on the computer during factory setup, or perhaps the error was introduced via the network interface controller...) Having modified `rails.bat` to point to the correct path the `rails` command now works fine from the shell. Thank you to [@SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) for helping to point me in the right direction.

If other people have similar issues they might wish to have a look in the `rails.bat` file in their `bin` directory. The correct `.bat` file for my system was:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe"     "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```